# How to extract a list of information from a regex group?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

I have multiple texts that are all structured as follows:

```
> Record:     24G3KL
> Source:     Whatever
> System Time:Oct 10, 2017 19:01:00 (MST)
> Result:     finalText
```

There is some more text before and after this, but it does not matter.

The goal is to extract the 6 alphanumeric chars value (here "24G3KL") everytime we meet a line with `> Result:     finalText`. The word "finalText" can differ (for example, it can be abcdefText or anything else). I am only interested in the value "finalText".

I am using the following regex:

```
([A-Z0-9]{6})(?:.|\n)*(?:\s*finalText)
```

It works fine, and the 6 alphanumeric chars value is extracted to the regex Group 1.

In Notepad++, I use the Find window, put my regex in the "Find what:" field, select Regular expression and click on the button Find All in Current Document.

The result is a list looking like this:

```
Line 85186: > Result:     finalText
Line 86200: > Result:     finalText
Line 87258: > Result:     finalText
Line 87721: > Result:     finalText
Line 87761: > Result:     finalText
```

I find this weird because "finalText" is not captured by the regex (starting with "?:"). I would expect to see my Group 1 (all my 6 alphanumeric chars values), instead of that.

[EDIT]
Here is what I receive:
[image: picture1]

In the Find result window at the bottom, I would expect to see the 6 alphanumeric chars values instead of the "finalText" values...

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: At a first glance, the result you get with Notepad++ perfectly matches your regex. So I don't understand how this regex could give you the "Record:" reference in another context (which one?).

Comment: I'm not sure your regex is correct. It looks like `(?:.|\n)*(?:\s*finalText)` will search until it finds a `finalText`, skipping over any other `Result:` lines that don't match `finalText`. So you'll capture `Record` strings you don't want.

Comment: See: https://regex101.com/r/L7DQlv/1 for what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it matches perfectly, use $1 to capture the contents of the first brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
([A-Z0-9]{6})\n.*\n.*\n> Result:\W*finalText
```

And that seems to work:

[image: screenshot]

This is assuming that there are always exactly two lines between Record and Result, though.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `> Record:\h*[A-Z0-9]{6}(?:\R.+){2}\R> Result:\h*finalText`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
> Record:\h*    : literally "> Record:" followed by 0 or more horizontal spaces
[A-Z0-9]{6}     : 6 upper case letter or digit
(?:             : non capture group
  \R            : a line break
  .+            : 1 or more any character
){2}            : must be present twice
\R              : a line break
> Result:\h*    : literally "> Result:" followed by 0 or more horizontal spaces
finalText       : literally "finalText"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Search "> Record:\h*[A-Z0-9]{6}(?:\R.+){2}\R> Result:\h*finalText" (2 hits in 1 file)
  new 2 (2 hits)
    Line 1: > Record:     24G3KL
    Line 9: > Record:     RNG3VS
```